# Preventing keyCode 13 trigger on Firefox browser suggest

Tags: javascript

In my code, if you start typing your ermail in the form input and then use the down-arrow key to select an auto-suggest entry, and press ENTER, the function will trigger, even though I'm not pressing ENTER on the actual input.

```js
function sysOnEnter(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('key was enter');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="email" onkeypress="sysOnEnter(event)">
```

Comment: When use the down-arrow key to select an auto-suggest entry, and press ENTER, the function will **not** trigger, in Chrome at least, so what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, the issue appears specific to Firefox.

Comment: Turns out this is a known bug, first reported 14 years ago!! https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=286933

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After more research I managed to answer my own question.

```js
function sysOnEnter(event, id) {
  
  var key = event.key || event.keyCode;
  
  if (key == 'Enter' || key == 13) {
  
    var val = document.getElementById(id).value;
  
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (document.getElementById(id).value == val)
        console.log('captured ENTER event');
    },0);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="email" onkeypress="sysOnEnter(event, this.id)">
```